# SAP .Net Connector with PowerShell : open PDFs in SAP system

Tags: powershell, sapui5, sap-dotnet-connector

I wrote an auto-login script into my sap, with PowerShell with importing SAP Connector for Microsoft .NET 3.0 (https://support.sap.com/en/product/connectors/msnet.html).
I tried to write a specific script, but I couldn't implement it. The programming guide and the tutorial for SAP Connector for Microsoft .NET 3.0 didn't help in my specific case. I try to implement a script that automatically logs into SAP system, and show the bills of a specific number.

Here is what I got so far:

```
    Function Load-NCo2 {

      $CurrentDir = Get-Location
      [System.IO.Directory]::SetCurrentDirectory($CurrentDir.Path)

      $Size = [System.IntPtr]::Size
      if ($Size -eq 4) {
        $Path = $CurrentDir.Path + "C:\Program Files\SAP\SAP_DotNetConnector3_Net40_x64\"
      }
      elseif ($Size -eq 8) {
        $Path = $CurrentDir.Path + "C:\Program Files\SAP\SAP_DotNetConnector3_Net40_x64\"
      }

      $rc = [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("C:\Program Files\SAP\SAP_DotNetConnector3_Net40_x64\" + "sapnco.dll")
      $rc = [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("C:\Program Files\SAP\SAP_DotNetConnector3_Net40_x64\" + "sapnco_utils.dll")

    }

      #-Function Get-Destination--------------------------------------------
    Function Get-Destination2 {

      #-Verbindungsparamter---------------------------------------------
        $cfgParams = New-Object SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcConfigParameters
        $cfgParams.Add("NAME", "SAPconnect")
        $cfgParams.Add("ASHOST", "t30")
        $cfgParams.Add("SYSNR", "10")
        $cfgParams.Add("CLIENT", "110")
        $cfgParams.Add("USER", "testuser")

        $cfgParams.Add("SYSID ","test.berlin.lan")
        $cfgParams.Add("LANG","DE")
        $cfgParams.Add("USE_SAPGUI",3)

        #$SecPasswd = Read-Host -Prompt "Passwort" -AsSecureString
        #$ptrPasswd = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBStr($SecPasswd)
        #$Passwd = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringBStr($ptrPasswd)
        $cfgParams.Add("PASSWD", "test")
        $cfgParams.Add("LCHECK",1)

      return [SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcDestinationManager]::GetDestination($cfgParams)

    }
      

    Load-NCo2
    Get-Destination2
```

Comment: What is your exact question, could you clarify what is behind "open PDF in SAP system"?  (SAP has many software, and there are many places in each software where PDF are stored) What means "open", do you mean just extract it from SAP software and you take care of displaying it? Remember that your question must remain focused on one precise problem, don't mix SAP .NET Connector (how to extract) and SAPUI5 (how to display) questions.

Comment: Hi @SandraRossi, with the script, i want to open specific delivery notes with for example "sap_object" = "xzy" or the "Object_id"= "xzy". and just extract it from sap and display it.

Comment: The "just" is in fact too much for one question, as I said, otherwise the answers will mix everything and it's not [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). I think you'd better split it into two distinct questions, one for PDF extraction from SAP via SAP .NET Connector, and one for displaying the PDF from a SAPUI5. In the second question, maybe you could also explain how you connect your SAPUI5 app to the PowerShell script, etc.